# discord.js v13 how to send message in a channel in another server

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

i'm using discord.js v13 and i was trying to send a message in another server's channel from where the slash commands was used

```
const channel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get("id")
channel.send({
            content: "<@&890249127907172407>",
            embeds: [Embed],
            components: [row]
})
```

but i get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Guild#channels`, which only holds the channels from that guild. You may instead want to use `Client#channels`, which holds all the channels in all the guilds the bot is in, as long as you have `GUILDS` intent.

```js
const channel = client.channels.cache.get(id)
channel.send({
  content: "...",
  embeds: [Embed],
  components: [row]
})
```

Comment: Or, if `client` is not available, OP can use `interaction.client.channels.cache.get()`